# New-MailboxExportRequest error when running from CMD

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I have a very simple PowerShell script that runs the new-mailboxexportrequest command. if I run the script as a scheduled task, I get the following error:
**new-mailboxexportrequest : Failed to communicate with the mailbox database.**
If I open the PowerShell command prompt, and run the script, I get the same error.
The script only works when I manually open the **exchange management shell** and run the script.

Keep in mind that the first line of the script actually has the exchange snapin command:
**add-pssnapin Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.E2010**

The question is, what loads from the exchange management shell that doesn't load on when the snapin runs?

Also, the scheduled task, the manual powershell command and the exchange management shell commands are running on the same box (exchange server). I'm also running them with the same user account.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the reason for your problem is explained in this link:

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/rmilne/2015/01/28/directly-loading-exchange-2010-or-2013-snapin-is-not-supported/

this should fix your problem :

```
    $Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri http://<ServerFQDN>/PowerShell/ -Authentication Kerberos
Import-PSSession $Session
```

you can check this also :

```
powershell -psconsolefile "C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\Bin\exshell.psc1" your-exchange-command
```